# SingleStore UTF-8mb4 support - or where are the emojis?

Tags: mysql, singlestore

I recently saw that UTF-8mb4 support is a listed exception 31 from MySQL. This means data with emojis (which our data set contains) returns an error on load.

Are there plans to support full UTF-8mb4, and as a result, emojis on the roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Singlestore now provides support to UTF8-MB4 encoding where you can save desired emojis in Database.

You can specify the character set and collation for the table using charset and/or collation options. Supported values for charset are `binary, utf8, and utf8mb4` . Supported values for collation can be viewed as the output of `SHOW COLLATION`  SQL query. Default collations for the corresponding charcter sets are binary, `utf8_general_ci` , and `utf8mb4_general_ci`.